# Reverse effect of evenodd in Svg

Tags: html, svg

I started learning SVG. Using polygons I have created a Star. While further reading I found a fill-rule property which can take two attributes first one is nonzero which will fill colour in whole the shape and another one is evenodd which will fill colour in odd points and even points will remain unfilled. When I used evenodd it filled the outer part of the star and left the centre blank.
How can I fill the centre or even points only of the star?

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    
    <svg height="210" width="500">
      <polygon points="100,10 40,198 190,78 10,78 160,198" style="fill:lime;stroke:purple;stroke-width:5;fill-rule:evenodd;"/>
      Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
    </svg>
    
    </body>

</html>
```

This will generate a star ditto to the 1st image[Side-Filled star](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2n5A.png)

and I want only center to be filled check 2ndimage.[Cneter fill star only](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZx8B.png)

Comment: you could rotate the star maybe.

Comment: The default behaviour of even-odd would be the opposite of what you are getting. So, your star must be "strange". Please post your SVG so that we can help you.

Comment: @RobertLongson Even-odd should be paint order independent ...

Comment: @vals,@RobertLongson i  have added code could you please help me to get that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> evenodd which will fill colour in odd points and even points will remain unfilled.

That sounds to me like you are misunderstanding what even-odd fill is.  The [description from the SVG specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/single-page.html#painting-FillRuleProperty) describes it this way:

> This rule determines the "insideness" of a point on the canvas by drawing a ray from that point to infinity in any direction and counting the number of path segments from the given shape that the ray crosses. If this number is odd, the point is inside; if even, the point is outside.

So in the case of your star, an imaginary line from a point in the centre of the star to the outside of the star always crosses two lines. So the inside is not considered part of the fill.

> How can I fill the centre or even points only of the star?

I don't know what you mean by this. What are the "even points" of the star?

Do you mean that you want to choose which of the six parts (center + 5 points) of the star get filled?  If so, then `fill-rule` won't help you. You will need to create and fill those shapes yourself.

For example:

```html
<svg height="210" width="500">
  <!-- centre -->
  <polygon points="78,78 122,78, 136,121 100,150 64,121" style="fill:lime;"/>

  <polygon points="100,10 40,198 190,78 10,78 160,198" style="fill:none;stroke:purple;stroke-width:5;"/>
</svg>
```